# ghdl elaborate an entity in a package

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I have a VHDL program and I can't elaborate it with GHDL, because the entity to elaborate is in a package. How do I elaborate an entity in a package with GHDL?

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers, after some time I figured out that the code in a package was something like an interface and we are supposed to implement this component ourselves and I falsely assumed that it was complete. Sorry for the wrong question, I am new to VHDL and am learning the ropes and couldn't find any explanation on google since my assumptions were wrong.

Comment: Do you have some skeleton code you could show?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers below. This will (a) give credit to the people who answered and (b) make it easy for other people who have the same question to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe it is legal to put an entity inside a package. You can put types, subtypes, constants, signals, files, aliases, component, attributes and groups into a package.

So you can put a component definition, which can map to an entity, inside of a package. This is convenient so that you could put a component in a single shared package instead of putting it in the architecture of every design unit that needs to use the functionality of the entity.

Answer (score 5):

I'm quite confident that the VHDL standard does not allow to declare entities in packages. Only components, subprograms, signals, constants, types and subtypes can be declared there.